# Windows Vista to Windows7 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade, operating-systems

I have a Windows Vista Home Premium and I tried installing SP2 on it and It prompted me to install SP1. Then it stopped working when I installed SP1. I don't have back up that I can use to restore it.

When I use the Windows Repair mode I am unable to get access to few options none of which is working.
I do have access to the command prompt.

Is there way to restore this?
If I am planning to upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium what are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade to Windows 7 will require booting into Vista. Otherwise you'll do a fresh install, and your data and files will be placed in a folder called `Windows.old` in the root of `C:`.

Answer (score 0):

First to restore your Vista, use Windows system restore from the Recovery Environment

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html

Back up any personal data, the windows.old folder will not contain any folders you created on the C drive, so you may want to back those up if they exist.

Use the Upgrade advisor before installing W7
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15&displaylang=en

Then do your upgrade.